# Missing pipe-output from a console-subprocess in the main program (Pari/GP,cygwin?)

Tags: windows, delphi, cygwin, pipe, pari

I've a User-GUI (in Delphi 6, 32bit) for the mathematical console-program Pari/GP: I call the Pari/GP in an invisible subprocess-window and communicate using the pipes STDIN and STDOUT, and as far as I can recognize from the sourcecode in Delphi for the console-subprocess, also STDERR.

With Pari/GP version 2.2.11 up to version 2.4 or so everything worked fine, and I determined begin and end of a communication (which is asynchronuous) with the subprocess by waiting for **the prompt**. But since version 2.5 the pipes do no more get the prompt. However, when I start Pari/GP in a cmd-window, I have the full dialog, including the prompt. (I've Win7, 64 bit but this seems not to be relevant, the behaviour is the same in a virtual machine with XP, 32bit)

I do not have the source code of the Pari/GP-software, but one likely significant difference is between the versions, that the newer versions do not have an external cygwin.dll with them.

Q: is that behaviour already known and also its reason? A known workaround? Also hints what might be the most likely reasons were helpful.

---

As requested, a bit more background.
In Delphi-6 I use the procedure "createconsoleprocess" (implemented by Jedi-project) which provides a `writeln(<string>)` to the invisible subprocess and two slightly different permanent threads which wait asynchronously for the response through the pipe (I assume, `stdout`). That wörks still fine for all versions.
But in the old version at each response was the Pari/GP `prompt` (just some characters like the Dos-prompt in a Dos-window). appended to the last portion of an answer so I could parse the pieces of the response until the `prompt`-symbol occured and could then display that complete answer as Pari/GP-output via a stringlist to the user.

After version Pari/GP 2.5 that prompt is no more occuring, so if I do no corrections the user waits infinitely for the completing of the Pari/GP-response. It was impossible for me - be it by changing the softwareflags for prompting and echoing, be it by hackwise replace `stdout`by `stderr`in the pipe-definition - to produce the prompting. Crazy: if I just start Pari/GP in a separate windows-console via cmd then the prompt is there - as if there is a new pipe which is unknown to the `createconsoleprocess` but known to the windows-os and the prompt is sended through this new pipe.

The only possibly relevant and visible modification over the versions seems to be, that the older versions have a `cygwin.dll` with Pari/GP and the newer versions don't have that. But I've no idea about the cygwin-secrets despite I've downloaded bit of documentation earlier - but that's simply not my expertise...

Here is an image which shows the principle of the communication. We see the window of my GUI and it has a Pari/GP-subprocess with which it communicates in the background via STDIN/STDOUT-pipes provides by the CreateConsoleProcess-procedure.
[image]

I have also a precise debugging tool which displays accurately the flow of strings over the pipes. Simply in the newer versions the prompt-string is no more appended at the end of STDOUT-messages, (and I also cannot find it via STDERR-communication) but the simple cmd-console window ***has*** this prompt, so it must be anywhere around....

Comment: As for me, gp reads fine from stdin pipe for Win8 + PARI/GP 32-bit 2.7.3. E.g. `echo print(1+1); | gp -q -s 450000000` prints `2` to stdout as expected. Please, share your minimal not-working example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has determined that the unwanted behavior is due to the third-party application he is using rather than representing a bug in his own code.

Comment: Maybe too naïve, but have you tried to inspect the list of _defaults_ in Pari (type `default()` to see all, or `default(x,y)` to change the value of _default_ `x` into `y`)? There is a file `gprc.txt` in the Pari installation folder which contains some _defaults_ which are set at startup. Try commenting all lines in that file by prepending ``\\``.

Comment: @Jeppe - yes, I've tried everything accessible via Pari/GP, defaults, gprc.txt etc. No way: the prompt is no more visible - only if I open Pari/GP in a windows-console and have then only typewriter-functionality, no copy&paste, edit-facilities only on line-editor level, no scratchpads, no organizing of the output - just 1980ies interaction. Thus my GUI which wants to be helpful here...

Answer (score 1):

It seems, the problem is not one of the sort where some known cygwin-incompatibility etc were relevant, so stackoverflow might not have been the best place to ask this question, so I close the case here.

---

Searchresults: after looking into the c-sources of the Pari/GP-versions it seems to me that I found the reason. I could not find *write()* (or wraps around it) other than through *stdout* so that the idea, they might have introduced another/ a new type of pipe for the *prompt* seems void.

Although I'm not familiar with c-language it seems to me, that in a critical routine for putting the results to the output-channel there is code, *to remove* a previously added *prompt* string from the output-string before sending. There are some flags and *if* s and *else* s around this, so it might be that they determine earlier, whether the program was started by a dos/windows-console (then leave the prompt-string) or by some other process (then remove the prompt-string)- there is a flag called *isinteractive* which among others switches in that source-code-segment.

So the question of an influence of the missing cygwin.dll is possibly irrelevant for this specific question- except that *just this* is the reason for the flag not have been set...

I'll try to contact the software authors for a concrete help.